# How to make PHP email you at specific time of the day

Tags: php

I created form which is saving information into my database. I would like to create a page which will go everyday 11pm and pull information regarding to that day and email it to me.

This is my database structure:

```
1 ID    int(11)  AUTO_INCREMENT
2 Who   text     utf8_general_ci
3 Time  text     utf8_general_ci
4 What  text     utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: It would help to stop thinking of PHP in "page" terms. If you're stuck in a web-centric view, you'll miss the fact that PHP is a program like any other and can be scheduled to run at specific times by standard system tools, like cron.

Comment: @Extelliqent so you need to use crontab or scheduled tasks (as stated in my answer....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got shell access to the web server you can use crontab to set up schedules that will execute the php script at the given time.

This will work in the same way as someone browsing the page. Each time someone browses your page, the script runs. When a schedule starts --> the script runs. The only difference is that it's run by the local user and not an external user.

You'll just need to set up your script so that it works the way you want, then set up the crontab for it.

[Here's](http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference) a link that explains how to use crontab, which will get you started.

Comment: I can create a schedule task in my computer to openup a page then I can run the script and close the page. It would be much easier and faster way. But Thank you for your help it gave me good idea. I thought php would have solution for that.

Comment: It's possible to execute PHP scripts directly using the `php` command (e.g. `php stuff.php`), so if you can get it into a form that doesn't need user interaction, you can just run it directly without a browser being involved.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use either linux's crontab or windows' scheduled tasks.

Comment: I`m talking about webpage doing some action without browsing it.

Comment: @Extelliqent That is not possible.

Comment: ... or a long-running task that spends most of its time sleeping

Comment: @EugenRieck hehe that too, but that would kill a browser (as it seems the OP wants)

Comment: Would your cron job be something like "request this PHP page using wget"? Edit: Ah, I just noticed Marc B's comment.

Comment: @marnir no.... just a reg php call..

Comment: @Extelliqent, are you in Windows or Linux, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Use Cron Jobs or a PHP Bot. I would use the PHP Bot because then you don't have to use cron jobs. Just set a unix timestamp and a "SENT" Column in a database and you've got it.